# Does 'pip download' is portable?

Tags: python, pip

One can download locally packages requirements with a

```
pip download -d mydist -r req.txt
```

Then install them offline with a :

```
pip install -f mydist -r req.txt
```

I have to transfert 'mydist' directory to a host that is not exactly the same Linux : The 'pip download' is made on ubuntu, and the 'pip install' on a Centos server that do not have internet access.

Is that supported ?

Usually I use buildout, and I can see some compilations on some packages (lxml, pillow etc...). So I am wondering whether some hidden compilations can occurs on 'pip download' side that could create some 'undefined symbol' at 'pip install' side because the libraries are not exactly the same.